# What's wrong with my configuration for network install of Opensuse on ppc64?

Tags: opensuse, powerpc, ppc64

I want to try to install an opensuse tumbleweed on ppc64.

I have a server with dhcp and tftp, I have configured it

vim /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

```
allow bootp;
host ibmlinux {
hardware ethernet ***;
fixed-address 192.168.0.10;
filename "/core.elf";
}
```

this is the /srv/tftp directory contents (i have only omitted the modules to save space)

```
/srv/tftp
/srv/tftp/boot
/srv/tftp/boot/ppc64
/srv/tftp/boot/ppc64/grub2-ieee1275
/srv/tftp/boot/ppc64/grub2-ieee1275/locale
/srv/tftp/boot/ppc64/grub2-ieee1275/locale/en.mo
/srv/tftp/boot/ppc64/grub2-ieee1275/powerpc-ieee1275
/srv/tftp/boot/ppc64/grub2-ieee1275/powerpc-ieee1275/adler32.mod
/srv/tftp/boot/ppc64/grub2-ieee1275/powerpc-ieee1275/affs.mod
/srv/tftp/boot/ppc64/grub2-ieee1275/powerpc-ieee1275/afs.mod
/srv/tftp/boot/ppc64/grub2-ieee1275/powerpc-ieee1275/afsplitter.mod
/srv/tftp/boot/ppc64/grub2-ieee1275/powerpc-ieee1275/all_video.mod
/srv/tftp/boot/ppc64/grub2-ieee1275/powerpc-ieee1275/appended_signature_test.mod
/srv/tftp/boot/ppc64/grub2-ieee1275/powerpc-ieee1275/appendedsig.mod
/srv/tftp/boot/ppc64/grub2-ieee1275/powerpc-ieee1275/archelp.mod
/srv/tftp/boot/ppc64/grub2-ieee1275/powerpc-ieee1275/asn1.mod
/srv/tftp/boot/ppc64/grub2-ieee1275/powerpc-ieee1275/bfs.mod
/srv/tftp/boot/ppc64/grub2-ieee1275/powerpc-ieee1275/bitmap.mod
.....
/srv/tftp/boot/ppc64/grub2-ieee1275/core.elf
/srv/tftp/boot/ppc64/grub2-ieee1275/grub.cfg
/srv/tftp/boot/ppc64/initrd
/srv/tftp/boot/ppc64/libyui-rest-api
/srv/tftp/boot/ppc64/linux
/srv/tftp/core.elf
```

I turn on my ppc64 Workstation

on Openfirmware prompt I've typed

boot net and...

```
0 > boot net

BOOTP: chosen-network-type = ethernet,auto,rj45,auto
BOOTP: server   IP =        0.0.0.0
BOOTP: requested filename =
BOOTP: client   IP =        0.0.0.0
BOOTP: client   HW addr =   **********
BOOTP: gateway  IP =        0.0.0.0
BOOTP: device    /pci@800000020000004/pci@2,4/ethernet@1
BOOTP: loc-code  U787F.001.DPM5MVH-P1-T5


BOOTP: wait 60 seconds for Spanning Tree ...

BOOTP R = 1 BOOTP S = 2
FILE: /core.elf
FINAL Packet Count = 431
FINAL File Size = 220216 bytes.
load-base=0x4000
real-base=0x2000000

Elapsed time since release of system processors: 3 mins 13 secs
Calling ibm,client-architecture-support...done
Welcome to GRUB!

error: ../../grub-core/net/net.c:186:timeout: could not resolve hardware address
.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

What I miss?